# JS add text to a button using setAttribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using JS on a react project to 'setAttribute' of a button to set the text of a button but I can't seem to get the text to appear on the button...

I have tried both 'value' and 'innerHTML'

```
 var removeBranchBtn = document.createElement('button');
    removeBranchBtn.setAttribute('type','button');
    removeBranchBtn.setAttribute('value','Remove');
    removeBranchBtn.setAttribute('innerHTML','Remove');
```

but the button only looks like a small grey rectangle

[image]

In developer tools I can see they have been added

[image]

What am I missing or doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to set the textContent property ?

Comment: How did you come up with the name `innerHTML` without the context of how to use it correctly, by the way?

Comment: And why are you creating an element with the DOM API in a React project?

Comment: This is completely the wrong approach if you're using React. Creating HTML elements on the fly like that will just conflict and interfere with the way React reconciles changes. You should really look at the [React documentation](https://react.dev/learn) to see how to use the library properly.

Comment: thanks for the reply guys. I know its not perfect just looking for a quick fix now if possible? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`innerHTML` is a property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), not an attribute. In general, you should prefer using properties over attributes [when both exist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IDL), too: they’re easier to read and can represent richer types.

Also, the better property to use here is [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), since you’re just setting text whose HTML representation is incidentally the same.

```
var removeBranchBtn = document.createElement('button');
removeBranchBtn.type = 'button';
removeBranchBtn.textContent = 'Remove';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Ry- that has resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

If it’s a React project, use JSX: `<button>Remove</button>` or `<input type="button" value="Remove">`